# Custom dialog with background image is cutoff at the top

Tags: android

I am using the following xml as the content of my custom dialog

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/dialogue_base" >
.
.
.
</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see the background is taken from a background image. When I do it on my Galaxy phone things  look great. But when I try it on nexus then the top of the dialog is cut-off  although there is still some space left on the top (above the cutoff dialog) that is not being used.

How can I overcome this issue?

Thank you

Here is an image
[image]

Comment: can you try inside frameLayout  android:foregroundGravity="fill" ?

Comment: Cna you post the screenshot, so i can solve....

Comment: @RajeshVijayakumar, Here is the image. Sorry for late response. I had to get hold of the device that is generating that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer although it does not make sense. I had to remove the 
diag.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

I have no idea why removing it worked on nexus !! but it solved it